# Replicating data set A based on the number of observations in the column of data set B where both data sets have a matching values in 1 column

Tags: r, dataset

I have data sets A and B:

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to get the below outcome?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: possibly look into `?merge`.

Comment: Thanks! I've got the solution

Answer (score 0):

dfc <- plyr::join(dfa, dfb, type = "inner")
where dfa is Data Set A and dfb is Data Set B